# Disable quarter screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, window, window-manager

When I have a window on half of my screen and press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>, in Windows 10, the window smalls down to a quarter of the screen.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I'd like to stick with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> maximizing a window.

Comment: No; But this behavior isn't actually new to Windows 10

Comment: Quarter docking is indeed new to Windows 10 and a great pain at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only be disabled by a 3rd party product like AquaSnap:
https://www.ghacks.net/2015/09/17/aquasnap-lets-you-customize-windows-10s-snap-functionality/